# Error "System.IO.IOException: The process can not access the file..." at ELMA BPM service restart

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Is anyone can help me with this error? I work in ELMA BPM designer to create new document type. To apply changes I have to restart server from designer's Publish page. But restart fails with this error:

```
*EleWise.ELMA.Runtime.Exceptions.ConfigurationInitializeException: Could not initialize provider (EleWise.ELMA.Extensions.MSSQL.MSSQLProvider) ---> System.IO.IOException: The process can not access the file "C:\ELMA3-Standart\Web\App_Data\CompiledModel\EleWise.ELMA.ConfigurationModel.dll", because this file is used by another process. 
в System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) 
в System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) 
в System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) 
в System.IO.File.InternalWriteAllBytes(String path, Byte[] bytes, Boolean checkHost) 
в EleWise.ELMA.Extensions.IOExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2.ojGdPYsZsVXSCIcncMJy(Object , Object ) 
в EleWise.ELMA.Extensions.IOExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2.<WriteAllBytesWithAttempts>b__0() 
в EleWise.ELMA.Extensions.ActionExtensions.ExecuteWithAttempts(Action action, TimeSpan interval, Int32 attemptCount, Func`2 canRetry) 
в EleWise.ELMA.Extensions.ActionExtensions.ExecuteWithAttempts(Action action, TimeSpan interval, Int32 attemptCount) 
в EleWise.ELMA.Extensions.IOExtensions.V8SiNHPWKWSx55xVAVO(Object , TimeSpan interval, Int32 attemptCount) 
в EleWise.ELMA.Extensions.IOExtensions.WriteAllBytesWithAttempts(String fileName, Byte[] bytes, TimeSpan interval, Int32 attemptCount) 
в EleWise.ELMA.Model.Managers.ModelRegistrarImpl.gtNM326hspFGnkwJWMer(Object , Object , TimeSpan interval, Int32 attemptCount) 
в EleWise.ELMA.Model.Managers.ModelRegistrarImpl.Register(ModelRegistrar r, NHManagerRegisterParams parameters) 
в EleWise.ELMA.Model.Managers.ModelRegistrar.UfaKdxswFE3lDcr0dnAE(Object , Object , Object ) 
в EleWise.ELMA.Model.Managers.ModelRegistrar.Register(NHManagerRegisterParams parameters) 
в EleWise.ELMA.Runtime.Providers.NHProvider.sNUTU0slYESilTqkrdpp(Object , Object ) 
в EleWise.ELMA.Runtime.Providers.NHProvider.Init() 
в EleWise.ELMA.Runtime.RuntimeApplication.hoDmZpsRD8169HIgClCG(Object ) 
в EleWise.ELMA.Runtime.RuntimeApplication.InitProvider(IProvider provider) 
--- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
в EleWise.ELMA.Runtime.RuntimeApplication.InitProvider(IProvider provider) 
в EleWise.ELMA.Runtime.RuntimeApplication.vV6Ci8sREl65cvg3g8j0(Object , Object ) 
в EleWise.ELMA.Runtime.RuntimeApplication.Init() 
в EleWise.ELMA.ComponentModel.ComponentManager.S3XEv7YWCC6moQn6U26O(Object ) 
в EleWise.ELMA.ComponentModel.ComponentManager.<RegisterComponents>b__c(Object h) 
в EleWise.ELMA.ComponentModel.ComponentManager.InvokeInitHandlers(Action`1 action) 
в EleWise.ELMA.ComponentModel.ComponentManager.RegisterComponents() 
в EleWise.ELMA.ComponentModel.ComponentManager.iOqsdcYuK9kGiI5HFBNd(Object ) 
в EleWise.ELMA.ComponentModel.ComponentManager.Init() 
в EleWise.ELMA.ComponentModel.ComponentManager.mULmXFYu3IXZsc8MnIcS(Object ) 
в EleWise.ELMA.ComponentModel.ComponentManager.Init(String[] assembliesPaths, String workDirectory) 
в EleWise.ELMA.BPM.Mvc.Application.Orchard.ELMAEnviromentStarter.RqpX6RqgtspSri31B0(Object , Object , Object ) 
в EleWise.ELMA.BPM.Mvc.Application.Orchard.ELMAEnviromentStarter.StartApplicationInThread() 
Could not initialize provider (EleWise.ELMA.Extensions.MSSQL.MSSQLProvider) 
EleWise.ELMA.SDK 
в EleWise.ELMA.Runtime.RuntimeApplication.InitProvider(IProvider provider) 
в EleWise.ELMA.Runtime.RuntimeApplication.vV6Ci8sREl65cvg3g8j0(Object , Object ) 
в EleWise.ELMA.Runtime.RuntimeApplication.Init() 
в EleWise.ELMA.ComponentModel.ComponentManager.S3XEv7YWCC6moQn6U26O(Object ) 
в EleWise.ELMA.ComponentModel.ComponentManager.<RegisterComponents>b__c(Object h) 
в EleWise.ELMA.ComponentModel.ComponentManager.InvokeInitHandlers(Action`1 action) 
в EleWise.ELMA.ComponentModel.ComponentManager.RegisterComponents() 
в EleWise.ELMA.ComponentModel.ComponentManager.iOqsdcYuK9kGiI5HFBNd(Object ) 
в EleWise.ELMA.ComponentModel.ComponentManager.Init() 
в EleWise.ELMA.ComponentModel.ComponentManager.mULmXFYu3IXZsc8MnIcS(Object ) 
в EleWise.ELMA.ComponentModel.ComponentManager.Init(String[] assembliesPaths, String workDirectory) 
в EleWise.ELMA.BPM.Mvc.Application.Orchard.ELMAEnviromentStarter.RqpX6RqgtspSri31B0(Object , Object , Object ) 
в EleWise.ELMA.BPM.Mvc.Application.Orchard.ELMAEnviromentStarter.StartApplicationInThread()*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to stop application pool and restart it a little bit later. Instant restarting sometimes fail because previous instance is still working. It's not a bug, just a feature.

Comment: Thanks, it helped, but there is no option to delay restart from the designer, right?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no option to have such type control of remote webserver, so in this case you should stop and start webserver manually.